# Android GridView actualizar backgroundColor de click anterior

Tags: android, gridview

Estoy cambiando de color las celdas de un GridView dependiendo de algunas comparaciones. Tengo un metodo que comprueba si el número es el más cercano a un número generado al azar, luego pinto de amarillo si la selección es más cercana que los que ya se han hecho clic. Pero quiero que el número más próximo anterior sea pintado de rojo, para no tener varias celdas en amarillo solamente dos. Codigo que compara y pinta las celdas:

```
gridViewNumbers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Random number is: " +randomNumber +" number is: " +listNumbers[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        int selectedNumber = listNumbers[position];

        numbersCloser(selectedNumber);

        if (selectedNumber == randomNumber) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        if (selectedNumber == numberBigger || selectedNumber == numberSmaller) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        if (selectedNumber != randomNumber && selectedNumber != numberBigger && selectedNumber != numberSmaller) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

        numberLastPlay = selectedNumber;
    }

});
```

Código que actualiza el número más cercano más grande y menor:

```
private int numbersCloser(int selected){
    if (selected < numberBigger && selected > randomNumber){
        return numberBigger = selected;
    }

    if (selected > numberSmaller && selected < randomNumber){
        return numberSmaller = selected;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Creo que tendré que crear variables para mantener los números próximos antiguos o cambiar el color a rojo de las celdas antes de actualizar las variables de números próximos. 
¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

> Creo que tendré que crear variables para mantener los números próximos
>   antiguos

Definitivamente tendrías que guardar en alguna variable los indices de las celdas de los números "antiguos", esto para  para cambiarlos a su color default, y posteriormente cambiar el color de las celdas correspondientes a amarillo verde y rojo.

Comment: SI, ya los crié! Y están guardando bien los valores.

Comment: Mi problemas es como hacer para cambiar el color de posiciones de celdas distintas del click! Que son los de las variables de los numeros anteriores.